# Em relação ao post no php

Tags: php

Então estou aprendendo o PHP a pouco tempo, e estou com uma dúvida, neste código eu consigo compilar normalmente com o get, porém quando uso o post, o código não compila, não mostra erros, percebi a pouco tempo, que um código que mandei pra um amigo com requisição do tipo post funcionou na máquina dele, alguém sabe dizer o que pode ter acontecido?

```
<form action="PassWord.php" name="CadastroForm" method="post">
    <label>
        <span>Senha:</span>
        <input type="password" name="senha" value="">
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar Dados" name="send">
</form>

<?php
    var_dump($_POST['send']);
    if (isset($_POST['send'])){
        $pass = $_POST['senha'];
        $pass = base64_encode(md5($pass));

        echo $pass."<hr>";
    }



?>
```

Comment: Tira aquele die() ali.

Comment: PHP não compila! É uma linguagem de Script, interpretada. Abraços.

Comment: @taiar, valeu cara, mas em outros pc's o código funciona com post, sabe dizer oq está acontecendo? e tirar die() não adiantou.

Comment: O seu arquivo se chama PassWord.php em todos eles? O diretório tá certinho?

Comment: você precisa inserir mais elementos do problema, como: Você está usando php puro ou alguma plataforma cms? esse arquivo **PassWord.php**  é o código abaixo do formulário?

Answer (score 0):

Seria interessante você colocar um print do ue aparece quando você executa o arquivo. Mas como não sei se o nome do arquivo no action existe, podemos remover o atributo action, fazendo com que o próprio navegador identifique o nome do arquivo. Além disso tenha certeza que você está executando o arquivo através de um servidor web com um interpretador php. Teste no [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/).

```
<form  name="CadastroForm" method="post">
    <label>
        <span>Senha:</span>
        <input type="password" name="senha" value="">
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar Dados" name="send">
</form>

<?php
    var_dump($_POST['send']);
    if (isset($_POST['send'])){
        $pass = $_POST['senha'];
        $pass = base64_encode(md5($pass));

        echo $pass."<hr>";
    }



?>
```